# What causes this error when importing 'react-native-google-mobile-ads'?

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, admob

I'm trying to add AdMob to my React Native project using the 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' package like this:

```
import mobileAds from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

mobileAds()
  .initialize()
  .then(adapterStatuses => {
    // Initialization complete!
  });
```

The error I get when I run the project for any platform is (npx expo start --web)

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react_native_web_dist_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.requireNativeComponent) is not a function
    at ./node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/lib/module/ads/BaseAd.js (BaseAd.tsx:155:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/lib/module/ads/BannerAd.js (AppOpenAd.ts:55:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/lib/module/index.js (useRewardedInterstitialAd.ts:47:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./scripts/ad_manager.js (YourLibsScreen.jsx:56:1)
```

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "funlibs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "npm": "^9.7.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^11.1.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "unit.js": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

What is causing the error? The 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' package does not list any compatibility issues with the version I am using, and I can not find anyone with the same issue.

I have tried:

```
Deleting node_modules and reinstalling
Upgrading packages
Cleaned artifacts and cleared cache, then rebuilt the project
Build on a different computer
Build using a different operating system
```

I tried building using EAS locally with the command:

```
eas build --platform android --profile development --local
```

It gives this error:

```
asgeir@DESKTOP-THTRHRB:/mnt/e/Projects/Fun Libs/FunLibs$ cat /home/asgeir/.npm/_logs/2023-07-12T15_07_11_817Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npx/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'eyJqb2IiOnsidHlwZSI6Im1hbmFnZWQiLCJwbGF0Zm9ybSI6ImFuZ[...]
```